# selected <UL><LI> using php / mysql / html

Tags: php, mysql, html, arrays, loops

My output in html is :

```
    <uL><li id="B1"></li>
    <li id="B2"></li>
    <li id="B3"></li>
    <li id="B4"></li>
    <li id="B5"></li>
    <li id="B6"></li>
    <li id="B7"></li>
    <li id="B8"></li>
    <li id="B9"></li>
    <li id="B10"></li>
    <li id="B11"></li>
    <li id="B12"></li>
    <li id="B13"></li>
    <li id="B14"></li>
    <li id="B15"></li>
    <li id="B16" class="active"></li>
    <li id="B17" class="no"></li>
    <li id="B18" class="no"></li>
    <li id="B19" class="no"></li>
    <li id="B20" class="no"></li>
    </ul>
```

If MySQL query result is equal to `6`, then `<li>` tag with `id` equal to "`B6`" should have class "`active`". All the `<li>` elements occuring after this active element should have class "`no`".

This shows images of horizontal rating between `0` and `10` and between 0.5 .
Example : 0 0.5 1 1.5 2 2.5 3 3.5 4 4.5 5 5.5 6 6.5 7 7.5 8 8.5 9 9.5 10
In the example above elements from `0` to `5` will be blue, element `6` will be white and elements from `7` to `10` are black.

How could I generate this using PHP and/or MySQL?

Thanks

Comment: Could you be more clear about what do you want to achieve? Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I edited using my mean ! Are you Ok ?

Comment: user1086738, I do not know what are you talking about. Your question has a very low quality and is on its way to be closed by the community. Unless of course you improve its quality. For now even the only person that answered your question does not really know what question are you asking. There are two votes left for your question to be closed, you have still time. Please read your own question and write it again in a way that will leave no doubts on what are you asking. Also please do not be rude, being rude is not welcome on StackOverflow.

Comment: I assume you have some language issues, thus I modified your question on your behalf. Please check if it correctly shows what you are asking for, then accept the edit or revoke it. And let me know if the edit was correct. Thanks.

Comment: The question has been closed in the meantime, so no other answers will be added until someone reopens the question, but here is something that may solve your problem: http://ideone.com/GE1LP

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if I understood the question completely but this piece of php code will output as you mention in your question

```
<?php
$result = 6;
echo '<ul>';
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
{
    if($i<$result) echo "<li id=\"B$i\"></li>\n";
    if($i==$result) echo "<li id=\"B$i\" class=\"active\"></li>\n";
    if($i>$result) echo "<li id=\"B$i\" class=\"no\"></li>\n";
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Thanks, This Worked but 1 - if result = 0 not worked ! 2 - i tested for advanced : 0 0.5 1 1.5 2 2.5 ....... 10 and this not worked

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot understand you. What it is supposed to output with 0, 0.5, 1, ... Code above outputs exaclty as you wanted

Comment: @user1086738: Abraham's solution did not work, because he probably did not know what exactly you needed. Also this solution is based on the assumption that numbers are incremented by `1`. If they could be incremented by other value (or if there is no constant increment), then please state it clearly within the question.